# Minha lista de todos é toda apagada quando eu tento apagar só um todo

Tags: react

Isto é a minha lista de todos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E isto é o que acontece quando tento apagar um só todo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei ver o que o todo retornava e deveria retornar um objeto mas em vez retorna isto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também tenho este erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o meu código da App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Form from './components/Form';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <div className="title">
          <h1><span suppressContentEditableWarning="true" contentEditable="true" id="name">Your name</span> todo list</h1>
        </div>
      </header>
      <Form todos={todos} setInputText={setInputText} setTodos={setTodos} inputText={inputText}/>
      <TodoList setTodos={setTodos} todos={todos}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Eis o meu código da TodoList.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';

const TodoList = ( {todos, setTodos}) => {
  return(
    <div className="todo-list">
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <Todo setTodos={setTodos} todos={todos} todo={todo} key={todo.id} text={todo.text}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoList;
```

Eis o meu código da Todo.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BsCheck, BsTrashFill} from 'react-icons/bs';

const Todo = ({text, todos, setTodos, todo}) => {
  const deleteHandler = () => {
    console.log(`Before deleting: ${todos}`);
    setTodos([ todos.filter(el => el.id !== todo.id )]);
    console.log(`After deleting: ${todos}`);
  }

  return(
    <div className="todo">
      <p className="todo-text">{text}</p>
      <BsCheck id="check" size={30}/>
      <BsTrashFill onClick={deleteHandler} id="trash" size={30}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Todo;
```

Como é que eu ponho a funcionar direito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seu erro se encontra nesse trecho:

```
setTodos([ todos.filter(el => el.id !== todo.id )]);
```

A função `filter` por si só já retorna um array, se você fizer o `setTodos` dessa forma você terá uma estrutura semelhante a essa:

```
todos = [
  [{ ... }, { ... }]
]
```

Para resolver isso você pode utilizar o `spread operator`

```
setTodos([...todos.filter(el => el.id !== todo.id )]);
```

Ou simplesmente fazer dessa forma

```
setTodos(todos.filter(el => el.id !== todo.id ));
```